# Merging a dataframe in a dict with another dataframe in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have a dict that currently looks like this:

```
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13'],'Value':[1,1,1,1,1,1],'Type':['SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M'],'Desc':['Check SP','Check 1M','Check 3M','Check SP','Check 1M','Check 3M']}
import pandas as pd
df1= pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date','Value','Type','Desc'])
dict = {}
dict = {'Check':df1}
print dict
```

I am trying to append the appended df to the df element of this dict such as:

```
appended_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13'],'Value':[1,1,1],'Type':['SP','1M','3M'],'Desc':['Check SP','Check 1M','Check 3M']}
import pandas as pd
appended = pd.DataFrame(appended_data,columns=['Series_Date','Value','Type','Desc'])
print appended

adfs = {k:df.merge(appended[appended.Desc==df.Desc],on=['Series_Date'],how='left',suffixes=['','_Appended']) for (k,df) in dict.items()}
```

However, on running this merge statement, I get the following error: ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects

Tried reading on thie error but not sure how it's applicable here, any thoughts what could be done to get over this error or alternatively, another approach to do

Comment: The `dict` and the `.merge` don't cause this error. The message is pretty clear about the problem, the Series you are comparing ( `appended.Desc==df.Desc`)don't have identically labeled indices. Did you try googling for the error?

Answer (score 0):

using **'pd.concat'** can do the job here.

```
import pandas as pd
raw_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-10','2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13'],'Value':[1,1,1,1,1,1],'Type':['SP','1M','3M','SP','1M','3M'],'Desc':['Check SP','Check 1M','Check 3M','Check SP','Check 1M','Check 3M']}
df1= pd.DataFrame(raw_data,columns=['Series_Date','Value','Type','Desc'])
print 'df1:\n', df1

appended_data = {'Series_Date':['2017-03-13','2017-03-13','2017-03-13'],'Value':[1,1,1],'Type':['SP','1M','3M'],'Desc':['Check SP','Check 1M','Check 3M']}
appended = pd.DataFrame(appended_data,columns=['Series_Date','Value','Type','Desc'])
print 'appended\n:',appended

df_concat =pd.concat([appended,df1],axis=0)
print 'concat\n:',df_concat
```

Will results with:

```
df1:
  Series_Date  Value Type      Desc
0  2017-03-10      1   SP  Check SP
1  2017-03-10      1   1M  Check 1M
2  2017-03-10      1   3M  Check 3M
3  2017-03-13      1   SP  Check SP
4  2017-03-13      1   1M  Check 1M
5  2017-03-13      1   3M  Check 3M
appended
:   Series_Date  Value Type      Desc
0  2017-03-13      1   SP  Check SP
1  2017-03-13      1   1M  Check 1M
2  2017-03-13      1   3M  Check 3M
concat
:   Series_Date  Value Type      Desc
0  2017-03-13      1   SP  Check SP
1  2017-03-13      1   1M  Check 1M
2  2017-03-13      1   3M  Check 3M
0  2017-03-10      1   SP  Check SP
1  2017-03-10      1   1M  Check 1M
2  2017-03-10      1   3M  Check 3M
3  2017-03-13      1   SP  Check SP
4  2017-03-13      1   1M  Check 1M
5  2017-03-13      1   3M  Check 3M
```

Comment: Doesn't really work in my case as I am trying to append columns for a DF inside a dict.

Answer (score 0):

How about merging on both `desc` and `Series_date`

`adfs = {k:df.merge(appended,on=['Desc' , 'Series_Date'], how='left',suffixes=['','_Appended']) for (k,df) in dict.items()}`

A statement like `appended.Desc == df.Desc` is problematic, as these series are of different shape. You can try `isin`, such as `appended.Desc.isin(df.Desc)`.